# set css grid layout equal height rows

Tags: css, css-grid

How do I set equal height rows in css grid layout?

HTML:

```css
.wrapper {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100px);
  display: grid;
}

.inbox-side {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.nested-grid {
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  grid-column: 2/ -1;
}

.inbox-mail-rows {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10px, auto-fill), minmax(10px, auto-fill)); */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10px,1fr) minmax(200px,2fr));
}

.inbox-row-content {
  grid-column: 2 /-1;
}

.inbox-side div, .inbox-mail-rows {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #555;
}

/* .inbox-mails {
  grid-column: 1;
} */
```

```html
<div class="wrapper container">
  <div class="inbox-side">
    <div class="inbox-inbox">Inbox</div>
    <div class="inbox-pending">Pending</div>
    <div class="inbox-accepted">Accepted</div>
    <div class="inbox-declined">Declined</div>
  </div>
  <div class="nested-grid">
    <div class="inbox-mails">
      <div class="inbox-mail-rows">
        <div class="inbox-checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="inbox-row-content">Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</div>

      </div>
      <div class="inbox-mail-rows">
        <div class="inbox-checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="inbox-row-content">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="inbox-mail-rows">
        <div class="inbox-checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="inbox-row-content">1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why u have uploaded the same code twice?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows

Comment: @DeepshikaS yes so that you will see and reply :)

Answer (score 1):

The input has default `top` and `bottom margin` of `3px` that is why it was uneven remove it by making `margin:0;`

```css
.wrapper {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100px);
  display: grid;
}

.inbox-side {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.nested-grid {
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  grid-column: 2/ -1;
}

.inbox-mail-rows {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10px, auto-fill), minmax(10px, auto-fill)); */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10px,1fr) minmax(200px,2fr));
}

.inbox-row-content {
  grid-column: 2 /-1;
}

.inbox-side div, .inbox-mail-rows {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #555;
}

/*new code*/
input
{
margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper container">
  <div class="inbox-side">
    <div class="inbox-inbox">Inbox</div>
    <div class="inbox-pending">Pending</div>
    <div class="inbox-accepted">Accepted</div>
    <div class="inbox-declined">Declined</div>
  </div>
  <div class="nested-grid">
    <div class="inbox-mails">
      <div class="inbox-mail-rows">
        <div class="inbox-checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="inbox-row-content">1</div>

      </div>
      <div class="inbox-mail-rows">
        <div class="inbox-checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="inbox-row-content">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="inbox-mail-rows">
        <div class="inbox-checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="inbox-row-content">1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clue but for me setting label margin to zero worked

Comment: but when the content grows on right, the rows on the left are not matched to the right

Comment: @kittu can you show a example of what you are trying to say ?

Comment: Actually that's fine. Stretching the box on left doesn't make sense. Thanks anyway for quick reply

Comment: @kittu never mention :)